# pytest truncates assert message, when message is a list/dict of long strings

Tags: python, pytest

The assert keyword in python takes an expression, and an optional message to display. The message is useful when running pytest.

```
assert False, 'My message'
```

In addition to strings, you can raise any object, for example a dict or list.

However, pytest will truncate it if the message is a list with long strings:

```
def test():
    assert False, ['a' * 1000, 'a' * 1000, 'a' * 1000]
```

Pytest will show this which is confusing, because it appears like one item in the list instead of three:

```
    def test():
>       assert False, ['a' * 1000, 'a' * 1000, 'a' * 1000]
E       AssertionError: ['aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa']
E       assert False
```

**How can I prevent pytest from truncating the assert message if the message is a list/dict with long strings?**

The same is true for dictionaries, pytest makes it look like there is only one item in the dictionary, not three:

```
def test():
    assert False, {'foo': 'a' * 1000, 'bar': 'a' * 1000, 'baz': 'a' * 1000}
```

```
    def test():
>       assert False, {'foo': 'a' * 1000, 'bar': 'a' * 1000, 'baz': 'a' * 1000}
E       AssertionError: {'bar': 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'}
E       assert False
```

The interesting thing is that if you convert it to a string it will not truncate the string:

```
def test():
    assert False, '\n'.join(['a' * 1000, 'a' * 1000, 'a' * 1000])
```

I don't want to have to remember to do this everytime I am returning a list of long strings.

Comment: Maybe try running pytest with `-vv` flag.  Also consider the `icdiff` plugin to compare dicts.  https://pypi.org/project/pytest-icdiff/

Answer (score -2):

pytest rewrites all the assertions it finds in the source code unless you explicitly disable this behaviour. To disable with

```
pytest test.py --assert=plain
```

Or by writing it in the module docstring

```
"""module xyz
PYTEST_DONT_REWRITE
"""
```

You can find [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/assert.html#disabling-assert-rewriting) the documentation and, if you are interested, [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/main/src/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py#L607) the implementation of the visitor that rewrites all the `assert` statement.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. OP wants to know how prevent the truncation, not disable the output altogether.